# Calculate odds ratios for continuous variables

Tags: odds-ratio

I am at the **univariable** stage of my analysis, and I am looking at significance of individual variables/predictors.  I've tested each predictor for significance by Wilcoxon Rank-Sum for continuous variables (not using t-test because data are not necessarily normal) and chi-square for discrete variables.  However, in addition to p-values, I also need to calculate **odds ratios** (and 95%CI for the OR) for each predictor.

I was able to calculate ORs for the discrete variables using the (a*d)/(c*b) shortcut with a simple 2x2 table.  But I cannot find instructions for **how to calculate univariable ORs for the continuous variables**.

Should I run a separate logistic regression for each of the variables, where the independent variable is the continuous predictor and the dependent variable is my 0/1 outcome?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like some kind of variable selection for a regression model. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: What is a *"univariable stage of my analysis*" ? Please do NOT use the "significance" of variables in univariable regression models to inform which variables to use in a multivariable regression model. This is a terrible mistake.

Comment: @RobertLong Yes, understood.  No, I'm not hunting for p-values.  Working on a manuscript and need to report significance of predictors in both univariable and multivariable analysis.

Comment: Why in the univariate case? You don't have to do every statistically dubious suggestion a reviewer makes.

Comment: I'm glad you understand :) but in what sense is the significance of variables in univariate models relevant to your research question(s) ? How will these be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to compute odds ratios manually for continuous predictors. You need to run a one-predictor logistic regression, exponentiate the coefficient on the predictor and its confidence bounds, and then report that as the odds ratio and its 95% confidence interval. You can (and maybe should) do this with your binary predictors as well.

Comment: I realized this was a possibility just after posting.  Thanks, Noah.  I'm so used to working with multivariable regressions that I forgot univariable regressions are a thing, too :-)